# Arrays in php, Compare 2 arrays and keep duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays

The following is 2 different definitions of the problem:

How can I process 2 arrays so that I can keep the data of duplicate array[key] values.

I have arrays A and B.
I want to create array C with the children that their id/key values exist in both A and B arrays.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[array_intersect_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) seems to be what you're looking for